# UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, docker, socket.io, caffe

```
File "server.py", line 19, in do_GET
   message = classify_nsfw.get_score(self.path[1:])
 File "/home/adamsaj/Documents/nsfw-docker/classify_nsfw.py", line 133, in get_score
   image_data = open(file).read()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I am using `yahoo nsfw` module to read image file get score for every images...it's working on `python3` libs but i got error for `python` codecs file and am also try to change `utf-8` to `utf-16`,`latin-1`, format got same error.i cant solve this issues

Comment: You are trying to decode something as UTF-8 which is not UTF-8. Even if your locale is set to UTF-8, this does not mean that the data you are processing is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

It was working and after Mac Updates I started getting the same issue this morning. I just restarted the IntelliJ and the docker then it's just working again. This is a bit random but this works for me. :)